# Promblemas to send to call my method to a button

Tags: c#

I am learning to program in C # so my question is how to call the method from the button3
Look for information on the web but it is not very clear to me why I turn to this site

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
}

private void export2File(ListView lv, string splitter)
{
    string filename = "";
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

    sfd.Title = "SaveFileDialog Export2File";
    sfd.Filter = "Text File (.txt) | *.txt";

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filename = sfd.FileName.ToString();
        if (filename != "")
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem item in lv.Items)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", item.SubItems[0].Text, splitter, item.SubItems[1].Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    ListView listView1 = new ListView();
    string splitter = ",";

    export2File(listview1, splitter);
}
```

Comment: What items from a **blank** ListView are you expecting to be output here?

Comment: The items that Johnny adds. He asked how to call the method, and that's it. @Idle_Mind

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to the **ListView on your Form**, and the desired "splitter" into the method.  Assuming listView1 and a comma:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    export2File(listView1, ",");
}
```